# How to swap two objects in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class written for Fraction objects. I need to swap two Fraction objects, not the contents of the objects. Here is my code.

```
public void fswap(Fraction other){
    Fraction temp = other.copy();
    other = this;
    this = temp;
```

The copy() method returns a Fraction object identical to the object it was called on. The last line of this code throws an error in my IDE "cannot assign a value to final variable this". Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also see: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: just curious - why do you need this? why not just swap the content?

Comment: Do you mean, swap the _variables_ that refer to those objects, so that `a` becomes `b` and `b` becomes `a`?  I'm not sure what it would mean to swap the actual objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *cannot* write a swap method in Java that swaps the objects, not their contents.  It is literally impossible.  This is a distinguishing feature of a pass-by-value language, though it's always important to remember that Java passes *references* by *value*.

Comment: maybe worth noting that Java is in fact pass by value despite its ability to pass objects without copying.